# Force on pilot ejecting at supersonic speeds?

Tags: aerodynamics

Using the [Rayleigh drag equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_equation), and approximations for the air density, drag and frontal area of the pilot, and mass, at around 300 m/s (subsonic) a pilot might experience deceleration forces of about 40G. BTW, I assumed a drag coefficient of 1 since a Human being strapped to a chair is not especially aerodynamically slippery.

Now, if that was raised by another 100 m/s making it supersonic, how much would the force increase disproportionately?

Note that [one person has ejected at low altitude supersonic](http://jalopnik.com/5894022/what-happens-when-you-eject-out-of-a-jet-at-800-mph) and lived - just. So, how much of a difference does being on the wrong side of that dividing line make?

Comment: That would be one heck of a head rush! That guy is remarkably luck to be alive.

Comment: I would have expected his head to be twisted to one side so fast as to break his neck

Comment: Absolutely! I wonder if a suit to withstand these forces, and the forces described in your question could be possible

Comment: Precisely! at supersonic speed its a wonder he haven't burn up during re-entry.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of papers reporting [measurements of the drag coefficient of a sphere below and above supersonic speeds](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=drag%20coefficient%20sphere%20supersonic). Glancing through them, it appears the drag coefficient does increase as the speed goes supersonic, but by relatively modest amounts.

Obviously a pilot isn't a sphere, and the airflow will be affected by the presence of the plane, so I think we can at best guesstimate the drag. My guesstimate would be no *dramatic* increase in force with speed as the airflow goes supersonic.

Answer (score 1):

The acceleration needs to be provided here to conclude the net force on the pilot. 
Zero g: it shows free fall. Let me elaborate simply :
Weight= Mass × g force
Now in your case if the pilot goes to 400m/s in 10 seconds from a standstill, he will experience( i deem he'll feel it more than he experiences it :)) his weight FOUR the times as against whilst he ain't driving. 
Moreover, g force, the name seemed misleading to me, it shows the acceleration, instead of the force. g-force=force AGAINST gravity. A book resting on table, g-force=1g, UPWARDS. 
The example i presented, g-force=5g(assuming the pilot goes straight upwards).

Comment: The calculation I did provided a ballpark figure for the instantaneous maximum force he would feel upon ejection. That would obviously reduce quite rapidly